# Why thread both ends of a pipe for a pipe clamp?

Tags: clamps

I recently purchased [Pony Pipe Clamps](http://www.ponytools.com/index.php/pony/pipe-clamps) (#50 - 3/4 pipe).  In the instructions, they suggest to mount them on a pipe threaded at both ends.  My pipes are threaded at one end only.  I'm wondering what are the advantages to thread both ends.  Is this suggested just so that the movable part of the clamp doesn't slide off the pipe? (With the coil-spring stop installed)

Comment: Those spring thingies only add a very gentle "hint" that you're at the end (if you were really going to need them, i.e. carelessly sliding off the moveable part, you'd just shove them off). I don't think that is their true purpose, but rather they exist for ergonomics. The chrome-plated steel spring is somewhat less obnoxious than the naked (usually sharp and often rusty) screw when you grasp the pipe at the end. You're thus less likely to end up with small cuts on your fingers and pull threads out of your clothing every time you handle the clamp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the threaded ends can be used to extend the pipe to a longer length, the threads are used to hold a part that comes with the pony clamps. It is a piece of coiled wire that fits the threads so the sliding potion of the clamp does not come completely off the end.

Comment: I always thought that 'spring' was to protect the threads from getting damaged while using the pipes.

Comment: So THAT'S what those are supposed to be used for! I've just got a bunch of them sitting around in my tool chest.

Answer (score 9):

You can extend the reach of pipe clamps by connecting two together with a coupling. That requires that those ends be threaded.. Most people cant thread them at home, so it's better to get them threaded at the store up front so you don't have to make two trips :-)

Comment: Shall I assume that is supposed to read: Most people _cant_ thread them at home?

Comment: In addition, if you have both ends threaded, make sure to cover those threads with a threaded cap or coupling so they don't get damaged and thus make it difficult to use the threads.

Comment: Aren't all threads [canted](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Canted)? :)

Comment: This is (IMO) a better answer than the accepted one. Pipe clamps have some big disadvantages (staining, small throat depth), but the fact that you can easily extend them to any length is a real benefit and the most important reason to thread them at both ends.